# How do I fix Xbox 360 controller drift?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers

Occasionally when changing between loading screens or menu views I'll notice my cursor start to drift to the left (e.g., strafing left in a FPS, gliding left in a map screen). I take it that this shouldn't happen. If I gently nudge the left analog stick, it will reset back to normal. The stick isn't recalibrating back to center.

Is there an easy way to fix this? Is it a known issue? Is this covered under any recognized warranty? Did I wear it out? What's going on?

Comment: Mine goes down wards sometimes. Hope there is a nice simple fix..... my controllers are so old that I doubt they are covered by warranty which normally would be 3 months anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just wear and tear on cheap components. I got mine replaced under warranty, they were keen to help.

When the 360 is powered up, it sets the position of the analog stick as the neutral testing point. Any deviation from this is registered as movement. So when the stick is worn, it doesn't return QUITE to centre, causing the drift.

I'm not aware of a fix- if it is under warranty I would certainly request a replacement as it is affecting your gameplay.